# Invalid Permissions When Running Julius Speech Recognition on a Wav File

Tags: permissions, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

How do you use [Julius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_%28software%29) to convert a Wav file containing spoken words into a text file containing those words? I've read the [Julius Book](http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/test/htk--julius/julius) and I've downloaded the [Julius quickstart release](http://www.repository.voxforge1.org/downloads/Nightly_Builds/current/) on Voxforge. From the docs, I think I'm suppose to list the Wav file I want to process in another file, and pass the filename of *that* file to Julius via the filelist param.

For example, I have the `julius` executable and the other quickstart files (grammar files, conf, etc) in /home/myuser/test, and I have all my Wav files in /home/myuser/test/audio. `julius` is owned by my user, and has execute permission, and all the audio files have 777 permission. I have my filelist at /home/myuser/test/audio/filelist.txt, with lines like:

```
/home/myuser/test/audio/somewav1.wav
/home/myuser/test/audio/somewav2.wav
/home/myuser/test/audio/somewav3.wav
```

However, when I run:

```
./julian -input rawfile -filelist /home/myuser/test/audio/filelist.txt -C julian.jconf
```

I get the error:

```
./julian: line 1: /home/myuser/test/audio/somewav1.wav: Permission denied
```

I can't fathom why it can't access the file. It's owned by *my* user, running as *my* user, and reading a file owned by *my* user.

Why is Julius giving me this error?

Answer (score 0):

Just try using `sudo` Front of sentence. Like

```
sudo ./julian -input rawfile -filelist /home/myuser/test/audio/filelist.txt -C julian.jconf
```